# How can I use subquery to get the total price here?

Tags: sql, subquery

I have an orders, products and order details junction table. I need to find the total price of each order (price of all products combined for every order).

[image: https://imgur.com/eHRy6cr]

I need to output the order ID with the total price which is calculated by the quantity * price.
Here is what I have so far but outputs the same ID's over and over. It needs to be a subquery so joins won't help me here.

```
Select  order_id, (order_qty * p.price) as Order_Total
    From    order_details od, product p
    Where   p.product_id In
                (Select od.product_id
                From    order_details);
```

Comment: Why does it ***have*** to be a sub-query?

Comment: ...'cause I said so. Don't answer a question with a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
Select  o.order_id, sum((od.order_qty * p.price)) as Order_Total
From    orders o, order_details od, product p
Where   
o.order_id = od.order_id
and od.product_id = p.product_id
group by order_id
;
```

> Output -

```
order_id    Order_Total
50125   82
50126   80
50127   196
50128   178
50129   92
50130   98
```

Comment: Did you run that somewhere? I'd just like to see it for myself

Comment: Please note that I used random names and dates since they do not matter in the final output.

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering the question for three reasons  First, there should be an answer that uses proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Second, the answer should be syntactically correct.  And third, the query can be simplified because the `orders` table is not needed

```
select od.order_id, sum(od.order_qty * p.price) as Order_Total
from order_details od join
     product p
     on od.product_id = p.product_id
group by od.order_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

First to answer your question you can use JOINS which reduces complexity, among with this you can use a GROUP BY plus a SUM to make it easier which will result in a query like this

```
SELECT A.id, B.name, SUM(B.qty * C.cost) AS total FROM A JOIN B ON A.id = B.a_id JOIN C ON C.id = A.c_id GROUP BY A.id
```

*Im on a phone sorry if I am not specific in the query* :)

As an advice, I would recommend you to save in Order Details the value of the Product when you write it. This simplifies the query and will keep your sales records constant in time otherwise they will change everytime you update your product price